# Why are gradle.properties being applied to importing project?

Tags: gradle

I have two projects (`pA`, `pB`).

In `pA` I have:

- Some common Gradle build script files (like `foo.gradle`, `bar.gradle`).
- `gradle.properties` defining `propertyA=a`, `propertyB=b`.

In `pB` I am applying `foo.gradle` and `bar.gradle` like this:

```
buildscript {

  apply from: '/path/to/foo.gradle', to: buildscript

  ...
}
apply from: '/path/to/bar.gradle'
```

In `pB` I have a `gradle.properties` where I have `propertyA=blah`, `propertyB=moreBlah`.

I don't understand why I'm getting the propties in `projectB` as `a` and `b`.

I don't have these properties defined anywhere else.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Think that this is likely coming from not defining these in the root-project, but in modules A/B. `gradle.properties` usually resides in the root project - and is common to all the modules. And so if it only will get parsed once, this might explain the behavior; even if it may appear illogical, the order of execution (and parsing that file) might cause that. When flipping to order of modules, it should apply it the other way around. Better move it upwards by one level and find a better way to accomplish the task.

Comment: These are different projects. They are not under the same common root, they exist separately. They are not sub-projects, or modules of the same main project.

Comment: @carlspring the question is probably being presented too abstract to fully comprehend the situation. Gradle nevertheless might stick to the last one `gradle.properties` file it had read, while there is nothing which would override them (honestly, I haven't tried a similar setup so far).